# Generating valid inequalities to describe the convex hull of a set

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, convex-hulls

How to generate the valid inequalities needed to describe the below sets' convex hull?

```
S := {(x, y) : x + y ≥ b, x ≥ 0 integer, y ≥ 0}

S := {(x, y) : x + y ≥ b, x ≥ d integer}
```

What are the general guidelines to follow in such cases?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, is it the same for "S := {(x, y) : x + y ≥ b, x ≥ d integer, y ≥ 0}"?

Comment: The convex hull of the first set is $\{(x,y):
: x+y \geq b, x\geq 0, y \geq 0\}$.

Comment: Is $b$ an integer?

Comment: Is there any relationship between $b$ and $d$?

Comment: @RobPratt, b is not an integer, and there is no relationship between b and d.

Comment: Are $b$ and $d$ nonnegative?

Answer (score 0):

The general guideline for two variables is to plot the region.

Because $b$ is not integer, the convex hull of the first one is slightly more complicated than in the comment from @Kavi; there is one more inequality related to $(x,y)=(\lfloor b \rfloor, b - \lfloor b \rfloor)$ and $(x,y)=(\lceil b \rceil, 0)$.

The second one has a couple of cases depending on $b \le d$ or $b > d$.